# Interop C++ to C#, passing callback to c++ functions

Tags: c#, c++, interop, c++-cli, pinvoke

I am trying to use a native dll using DllImport in C#. Most of the methods are working fine but I am stuck in registering to callbacks. here is the sample:-

1. The function used for callback is `static int SetReceiver(IMessageReceiver* pReceiver);`
2. Definition for IMessageReceiver is

   ```
   class IMessageReceiver
   {
   public:
      virtual void OnMessage(unsigned char ucCommand, const void* pData, size_t size) = 0;
   };
   ```
3. In C++ it is done like this:

   ```
   class A : IMessageReceiver{ implementation of virtual function}
   SetReceiver(this); // this is object of Class A.
   ```
4. I want to achieve same in C#. What i did is created one Interface IMessageReceiver and implemented in class. I am creating the object of that class and passing it as parameter but getting exception.

   ```
   [DllImport("Native.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static extern void SetMessageReceiver(IMessageReceiver pReceiver);

   SetMessageReceiver(pReceiver);
   ```

Comment: This is not a _callback_ scenario. Your C++ function needs a pointer to a C++ Class, and this cannot be passed directly from C#.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to solve this from your C# code. You need to provide the implementation of a C++ class. And you cannot make one of those in C#.

The only way to solve this is with C++ code. I can see a couple of obvious solutions:

1. Use a mixed-mode C++/CLI assembly. That can implement the unmanaged C++ class and provide a bridge between the unmanaged C++ code and the managed C# code.
2. In your C++ code add a concrete implementation of `IMessageReceiver` that implements `OnMessage` by forwarding to a function pointer. The function pointer can be provided by the C# code. You'll need to wrap this up in a C style function so that you can p/invoke it.

Comment: Could you please help with some sample code to solve this? second option cannot be done as the c++ dll is 3rd party and nothing can be added to that.

Comment: I suggest you try yourself and ask again if you get stuck.